# Efficient Way to Count K-mers in O(k*N + k*Q)?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I have a string of lowercase alphabets. I need to find how many times each k-mer the question asks appears. The catch is I need to output the count in an order of k-mers the question asks. Another catch is I may need to output the count for the same k-mer more than one time. I need to accomplish this in O(k*N +k*Q) where k is the length of k-mer, N is the length of a DNA string and Q is the number of specific k-mers of interest.

For example, for the following input where N=7, k=2, q=3, aaabaab is the DNA string, the next 5 lines are the k-mers of my interest :

```
7 3 5
aaabaab
aaa
aab
aaa
baa
xyz
```

I would expect to output the following:

```
aaa 1
aab 2
aaa 1
baa 1
xyz 0
```

Note that aaa is asked twice!

I have a list of Q k-mers. I have a dictionary of k-mers with the counts (the length of a dictionary could be less than Q). With a for-loop, I iterate through DNA and each character while keeping tracking of a current k-mer O(N). In the next iteration, I update the current k-mer by dropping the first letter and append the current character. In order to output the answer, I iterate the list of Q k-mers and search for its count in the dictionary.

```
l, n , k, q = [int(x) for x in sys.stdin.readline().strip('\n').split(' ')]

dna = ''

for i in range(l):
    dna += sys.stdin.readline().strip('\n')

mykmer =[]
mycount = {}

for i in range(q):
    kmer = sys.stdin.readline().strip('\n')
    mykmer.append(kmer)   
    mycount[kmer]=0


current = dna[0:k]

for j in range(k-1,len(dna)): 

    if j != k-1:
        current = current[1:]+str(dna[j]) 

    if current in mykmer:
        mycount[current] += 1



for x in mykmer:
    print(str(x)+' '+str(mycount[x]))
```

I get correct answers, but I get timed out!

Comment: "Timed out"?  If you're solving a problem with such an interface, we need you to cite the original source.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem.  Your posting is over half input overhead that has nothing to do with the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

I would improve your inner loop to:

```
for j in range(len(dna) - (len(dna) % k)):
    current = dna[j:j+k]
    if current in mycount:
        mycount[current] += 1
```

Slicing once costs less than repeated slicing and appending. `current = current[1:]+str(dna[j])` costs more than `dna[j:j+k]`. As it results in 3 string allocations where as the slice results in one.

Use the dictionary you already have rather than the list to do membership tests on. This removes a factor of Q.

The `range(len(dna) - (len(dna) % k))` ensures that the loop does not unnecessarily consider the last few indexes.

Comment: Thanks! I like len(dna)%k. :)